# How to make function available once an action has occurred - jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a push style menu which shifts the content over to one side in order to reveal a menu list.  So far the menu works fine when opening and closing, although i would also like to add functionality which allows the user to close the menu by clicking anywhere in the content section.

I'm not really sure of how I can tie the 'close' function to the body container once the menu has been opened.

I've attempted using .bind() and .trigger() but I'm new to javascript/jquery and don't really understand how to make it work in this situation.

Here is the current function which opens/closes the menu...

```
$('.menu-button').click(function(){

    if(parseInt($('.site-menu').css('left')) == -144){
        $('.site-menu').addClass('site-menu-pushr');
        $('.site-header, .container-site-content').addClass('site-view-pushr');
    }
    else {
        linkClickUnpush();
    }

});
```

Since I use classes to carry out the animation I figured I could make a function which allows the content to be clicked on once the menu has been opened, but no dice! I don't know how to make the function run each time the menu has been opened since adding it to the click event above just breaks it.

```
function contentCloseMenu(){

    if($('.site-header, .container-site-content').hasClass('site-menu-pushr')){
        $('.site-header, .container-site-content').click(function(){
            linkClickUnpush();
        });
    }
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)?

Comment: @Mooseman - Not yet. I figured that .click() and .on(click, ...) would have the same effect so I didn't explore it.  Would you recommend .on() instead of .click() ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vafw5/1/

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu").on("click", function (e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).hasClass("opened")) {
            $(this).animate({left: "0px"}, 600);
            $(this).removeClass("opened");
        } else {
            $(this).animate({left: "150px"}, 600);
            $(this).addClass("opened");
        }
      });
    $("#container").on("click", function(){
        if($("#menu").hasClass("opened")){
            $("#menu").animate({left: "0px"}, 600);
            $("#menu").removeClass("opened");
        }
    });
});
```

click on the red square to open the menu, click again on the red square or everywhere in the yellow box to close the menu.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the example! Its a bit late in the evening so i'll give it a shot tomorrow. Whats the difference between .click() and .on(click,)?

Comment: have a look here or check the jquery documentation :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Comment: Hey, I tried it out and it worked just how I wanted, thanks! Although wouldn't the container script run every time a user clicked anything on the webpage? I was hoping to somehow merge the script so it only becomes available when the menu bar is showing, do you know how I could do that?... Or do you think that leaving it as is wouldn't make a difference to performance?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly what you need.. you want to make which script (or part) available when the menu bar is showing? the "close the menu" script?

Comment: I'd like to see if I can make the $('.container') part available only when the menu is open/showing. So if the menu is closed the $('.container') function wouldn't exist and clicking within the container wouldn't run any code.

Comment: bind the click funcion while the menu is open, unbind the click when it's closed

Comment: I'll look into that and give it a go. Thanks for your help